# How can i get bytes data using TCPSocket?

Tags: python, qt, tcpsocket

I want to use tcpsocket to send nv21 images between smartphone and server and convert it to rgb.I use Qt for android make the smartphone application and use python in server. When i use QByteArray to send the data, the picture is (1920*1080) so the size of data is 3110400. However i only receive 335620 bytes at server.
I want to know how can i send bypes correctly?

```
//QT client
void came::processFrame(const QVideoFrame& frame)
{
    QVideoFrame f(frame);
    QImage img;
    f.map(QAbstractVideoBuffer::ReadOnly);
    output.append((char*)f.bits(),f.mappedBytes());
    tcpSocket->write(output,output.size());
}

//Python server
def recvfromTcpSocket(sock, blockSize=4096, accept_addr=None):
    ''' a function to lisen TCP socket,
    and rece bytes till buffer has no more. '''
    d = ''
    while True:
        print ("Got tcp connection: " + str(tcpServerAddr))
        if accept_addr is None:
            break
        elif accept_addr == tcpServerAddr[0]:
            break
        else :
            sock.close()
            continue
    while True:
        block = sock.recv(blockSize)
        d += block
        if len(block) < blockSize and len(block)!=0:
            print ("TCP recv done, all size: " + str(len(d)))
            break
    return d

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data = recvfromTcpSocket(tcpServerSocket)
    bin_y = data[0:rows * cols]
    num_y = np.fromstring(bin_y, np.uint8)
    img_y = np.reshape(num_y, (rows, cols))
    bin_u = data[rows * cols::2]
    num_u = np.fromstring(bin_u, np.uint8)
    img_u = np.reshape(num_u, (rows / 2, cols / 2))
    bin_v = data[rows * cols+1::2]
    num_v = np.fromstring(bin_v, np.uint8)
    img_v = np.reshape(num_v, (rows / 2, cols / 2))
    enlarge_u = cv2.resize(img_u, dsize=(cols, rows), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    enlarge_v = cv2.resize(img_v, dsize=(cols, rows), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    dst = cv2.merge([img_y, enlarge_u, enlarge_v])
    bgr = cv2.cvtColor(dst, cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR)
```

Comment: Check the return value our write(), it can write any number of bytes, depending on the underlying buffers.

Comment: The return of tcpSocket->write(output,output.size()) is 3110400

Comment: You should call ```tcpSocket->write(output)``` as the output seems to be QByteArray and the size of QByteArray is known. There is no overloaded function that accepts both QByteArray and its size.

Comment: The output.size() means the max size.However, I tried tcpSocket->write(output) and not work too.